# How to get new IP address on boot up?

Tags: linux, debian, dhcp, ip-address

In Debian Linux, how can I get a new IP assignment on boot up? I'm working with VMs and I am required that every machine gets a new unique IP after booting up.

Comment: Do you have a DHCP server on the same network subnet as the VMs?

Comment: You should tag and rephrase the question to make it clear that you're on a VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably depends on your VM configuration, which in turn depends on the VM engine you are using. There are several ways to connect a VM to your network:

- the NAT, which is probably the default behavior, will explicitly use the same IP address as the VM host
- Host-only private network will not let you communicate with the external world, which is not very useful
- Bridge can do the trick but may be complex to configure
- Your best bet is probably "internal" network (VirtualBox terminology), which will look like another interface and can get a DHCP lease easily.

have a look at VirtualBox' documentation at http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Also be sure that all your VM guests have different MAC addresses, or else you will go into big trouble. Especially true if you create your VMs by copying (VirtualBox has a very visible option when duplicating VMs).

Comment: Yes! You are very right in that it depends on the VM engine. Apparently the VM itself does get the new IP address. It's just the engine that does not update correctly.